# Fetch details of the groups accessing document library in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to access the group information (group name and its members) who can access a Document Library in a SharePoint website.

Allow me to explain using an example:

For a site named "MyCompany" there are sub-sites as Finance, HR,etc. Each sub-site has a document library named "Shared Document", and in each Shared document has folders and sub-folders.
The access to these Shared Document is given to different groups like HR Managers are given access to Shared Document in HR sub-site.
I want to fetch the data of the groups that can access these Shared Documents as shown below:

```
Site     : MyCompany (URL/Title)
Sub-site : HR (URL/Title)
Folder   : Shared Document  (Name/URL)
Group    : HR Managers
Member   : John
```

I am able to fetch group information up to sub-site level. But enable to do so at document library and sub-folder level.

My script so far:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell   
Start-SPAssignment -Global

$sysdate = Get-Date -UFormat "%m_%d_%y" 
$sites = get-spsite http://MyCompany_Url

$sites
foreach($site in $sites)
{
    [array]$users = $null
    #$name = $site.RootWeb.Title
    write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$site.RootWeb.Title "..."
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
    {
        write-host  "--Working on web:" $web.Title "..." -foregroundcolor yellow
        $webTitle = $web.Title
        foreach($l in $web.Lists)
        {
            #Check for only document libraries
            if($l.BaseType  -eq "DocumentLibrary")
            {
                if($l.Title -eq "Shared Documents")
                {
                    Write-Host $l.Title"(Web: "$web.Title")" -ForegroundColor DarkRed -BackgroundColor White
                    $grpinfo = $l.RoleAssignments
                    $groupinfo

                    <#foreach($item in $l.Items)
                    {
                        $ItemUrl   = $item.Url
                        $ItemTitle = $item.Title

                        Write-Host $item.Url" : "$item.Title -ForegroundColor green 
                    }#>

                }
            }
        }
        # # Getting group ifo at sub-site level
        foreach ($group in $web.groups)
        {
            write-host  "----Collecting users from group:"$group.Name "..." -ForegroundColor Magenta

            #$GrpPermission = $roles.Type + ":"+ $roles.Name
            foreach($user in $group.users)
            {
                $usrname   = $user.DisplayName
                $UserPerm  = $user.Roles
                $GroupPerm = $group.Roles

                [string]$UPerm = @($UserPerm.Name) -join ","
                [string]$GPerm = @($GroupPerm.Name) -join "," #-replace (" ", ",")
                Write-Host "################"
                $GPerm
                Write-Host "----------------"
                $UPerm
                Write-Host "################"

                write-host "-----"$user.DisplayName" : "$group.name" : "$web.Title" : "$site.RootWeb.Title " Group Permission : "$group.Roles  " Member Permission : "$user.Roles -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor White
                $users = new-object psobject
                $users | Add-Member NoteProperty -name "Webpart Name"          -value $web.Title
                $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Groups"                -value $group.name
                $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Display Name"          -value $user.DisplayName
                $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Group Permission(s)"   -value $GPerm
                $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Webpart URL"           -value $web.Url
                #$users
                $users  | export-csv -path "E:\MyCompany_Groups_report_$sysdate.xls" -Append -NoTypeInformation             
            }
        } 
        $web.Dispose()
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```